# Vue.js - How to change image src on scroll?

Tags: vue.js, scroll

I would like to change the logo (img src) in the navbar if user scrolls down. How can I do it? I found only solutions where I can change the css.

```
<div class="logo">
    <img src="@/assets/img/Logo1.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: 1) Detect scrolling.  2) Get the scroll value.  3) Change the image source.  Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to listen to the scroll, then when the user scroll you check the value of the current scroll, if the value is enough for you to change the image you set in the state that you need to change the default image.

To allow the change to be dynamic you need to put a conditionnal render in your src attribute of the image with the images you want to swap.

The second condition on the handleScroll, is to re-put the default image if the user has scrolled less than 100, and only if it was not the default image

Here is the code to achieve it

```
<template>
  <div id="app" style="height: 1800px">
    <img
      style="position: fixed"
      alt="Vue logo"
      :src="
        isDefaultImage
          ? 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/t%C3%AAte-et-visage-de-portrait-mouette-adulte-harengs-semblant-droits-125872008.jpg'
          : 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg'
      "
      width="25%"
    />
    <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isDefaultImage: true,
    };
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll(event) {
      // Any code to be executed when the window is scrolled
      console.log(window.scrollY);
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        return (this.isDefaultImage = false);
      }
      if (window.scrollY <= 100) {
        if (!this.defaultImage) {
          return (this.isDefaultImage = true);
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Link to the code sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-brook-q5l3g?file=/src/App.vue